# Configure bean through annotation (java ee5)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5, seam2

I'm in need of configurating ejb through custom annotation (in java ee 5 environment).
How can I achieve it?

Here's a sample code which shall depict my problem better.

```
  class MyBigClass{
     @Configure(value=5)
     ConfigurableBean bean;
  }
```

and somewhere on the way, I'd like to set certain property in implementation of 'ConfigurableBean' with value of "5".

```
  class MyConfigurableBean implements ConfigurableBean{
     int myValue; // while DI process it's being set with 5
  }
```

I use jboss-seam2 in my product. Maybe there's a build-in component that might help me in achieving my goal.

I trully hope I have stated my mind clearly :)

Best regards, Miron

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in component for that but you may use a seam interceptor for that.

Comment: I've considered it, but it feels a little like a hack/work-around, than a proper solution ;-/

Comment: What do you feel the proper solution would be?

Comment: I'm looking for a way of injecting my annotation into j2ee container so it will be handled by it just like "native" - i.e. @Resource\@Inject - both of them can receive param(s) which will change their behaviour